# How do i change colors of two selected elements with css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-color

I'm working on some simple game for browser and i have this problem.

This is my HTML/PHP: (just 1 line that is important for this)

```
    echo '<div id="div'.$n.'" class="d'.$rand.'" onclick="swapit(this.id, this.className)"></div>';
```

I've got 4 different class names that are generated randomly and for them i got 4 different colors. And I'm using id just to know what exact element that is 'cause there are 13x8 elements like this randomly generated. ID is not random, it is increasing - 0,1,2,3,4...

This is my CSS:

```
.d0 {
    width:60px;
    height:50px;
    border:0;
    margin:8px 0 0 7px;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#0080FF;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
    box-shadow:0 0 1px #0080FF;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

I've also defined d1,d2 and d3 but with different background colors.
Id's are not defined anywhere in my css file.

And this is part of my JAVASCRIPT:

```
function swapit(id, classn)
{
    if(n == 0)
    {
        div1 = document.getElementById(id);
        color1 = document.getElementsByClassName(classn)[0].style.backgroundColor;      
        //alert(color1);
        //when i alert color1 it is blank       
        n++;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = color1;
        div1.style.backgroundColor = document.getElementsByClassName(classn)[0].style.backgroundColor;
        n--;
    }
}
```

What I want is when i click on some blue div and then on some green div.. I want blue to become green and green to become blue. But it seems that I'm missing something with that style.backgroundColor property.. 'cause it doesn't return anything.

So please, help me :)

Comment: `.style` returns the **inline** styles of the element, e.g. `<div style="this gets returned">`. In order to get styles from a stylesheet, you need to use getComputedStyle, as Ixe suggested, or you can use jQuery's `.css("background-color")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get the styles applied via stylesheets:

```
// ...
var $el = document.getElementsByClassName(classn)[0];
alert(getComputedStyle($el).backgroundColor); 
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that works fine now, but i also have one other problem now... my first div doesnt change in color of second div

Answer (score 1):

See these two for further discussion about usage in different browsers:

1. [getComputedStyle in pure Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675828/getcomputedstyle-on-pure-javascript)
2. http://caniuse.com/#feat=getcomputedstyle

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your answers, I just found one other solution that fixes all my problems.

```
function swapit(id, classn)
{
    if(n == 0)
    {
        div1 = id;
        class1 = classn;
        n = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('class', class1);
        document.getElementById(div1).setAttribute('class', classn);
        n = 0;
    }   
}
```