# How do I get the font style (font-family) from an element

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using angular, but I assume I can use any DOM manipulation for this ?

Comment: Yes, you can use any DOM manipulation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) and [`getPropertyValue()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration#Syntax).

Here's a running example:

```js
var test = document.getElementById("test");
var result = document.getElementById("result");
result.value = getComputedStyle(test).getPropertyValue("font-family");
```

```css
#test {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS",sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<span id="test">What font family am I?</span>
<input id="result"></input>
```

Comment: 2023 checkup: is there a way to get the name of the font actually being loaded and rendered?

Answer (score 2):

If you have jQuery you can use this:

```
$('#some-selector').css('font-family');
```

You can use vanilla JS too, but it is a bit more involved. Here is an example using `getComputedStyle`:
[getComputedStyle in pure Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675828/getcomputedstyle-on-pure-javascript)